# Android, How to detect and to do a task in mode idle_maintenance?

Tags: android, geolocation, android-doze, android-doze-and-standby

I need to send tracking info when device is in DOZE mode.

According to page [monitoring-device-state](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html) there are idle and idle_maintenance, I understand that when it is in idle_maintenance window, the applications can execute tasks. In my case I want to get tracking info and send to my server but my app is in block state when there is idle or idle_maintenance window.

How can I do a task in mode idle_maintenance?

**OR**

what library can I use?

**OR**

Any example?

first of all, Thanks.